ExpressJS res.render is not a function
I've searched on google but not yet found an answer so I write here. I am new in ExpressJS so this is my first Express application.
Here is my router:
loginRouter.post('/login', loginController.index)
Controller:
exports.index = (req, res) => {

//condition #1
if(req.body.username == '' || req.body.password == '') {
    res.render('login', {
        title: "Empty data",
        param: 1
    })
    return
}

//condition #2
const username = sanitize(req.body.username)
const password = sanitize(req.body.password)

const sql = "select username from tbl_user where username = ? LIMIT 1"
conn.query(sql, [username], function (err, res) {

    if(res.length == 0) {
        res.send("username not found")
        res.render('login', {
            param: 1
        })
    }
    res.render('../views/main/index', {
        param: 1
    })
})          


res.render('login', {
    param: 0
})

}

On a login page, if I hit login button without fill username and password, it will go to Condition #1 and render the 'login' page, so it is correct.
But if I fill some data on login page, it will go to Condition #2 and show error "res.send is not a function" which is on line "res.send("username not found").
What is wrong and what it should be? Please advice. Thank you.

change the variable name res inside the query callback into result

Avoid variable shadowing

It's just a reference mistake, you have both response res and result of query res with same name
So we can just change the res variable inside the query callback into result
conn.query(sql, [username], function (err, result) {

    if(result.length == 0) {
        res.send("username not found")
        res.render('login', {
            param: 1
        })
    }
    res.render('../views/main/index', {
        param: 1
    })
})  

